# Four Tic-Tac-Toe boards using kTurtle

Tags: beginner, game, logo-lang

I am trying to learn kTurtle (slightly different from Logo) so that I can help my daughter learn to write code.  I have decided that I would write a program that would play Tic-Tac-Toe with a user.  So far, all I have is the `Game` board, and I make it more than just a single board to add to the intensity of my learning.  Hopefully I can get this figured out before my daughter graduates high school.

I am using kTurtle on Ubuntu which is similar to Logo but open source (free).

What I really want to know is if I am following good programming standards as this is a little different than what I am used to coding.

```
#Game board 1
$CanvasX = 300
$CanvasY = 300
#$x = ask "how big do you want the canvas to be?"
canvassize $CanvasX, $CanvasY

$x=$CanvasX/2
$y=$CanvasY/2

learn gameboard $a, $b, $x, $y {
    $TwoThirdsX = ($x/3)*2
    $OneThirdX = $x/3
    go $a, $b
    dir 180
    penup
    forward $OneThirdX
    turnleft 90
    pendown
    forward $x
    penup
    turnright 90
    forward $OneThirdX
    turnright 90
    pendown
    forward $x
    penup
    turnleft 90
    forward $OneThirdX
    turnleft 90
    forward $OneThirdX
    turnleft 90
    pendown
    forward $x
    penup
    turnright 90
    forward $OneThirdX
    pendown
    turnright 90
    forward $x
}  
penwidth 1
gameboard 0, 0, $x, $y
$a=$x
$b=0
gameboard $a,$b,$x,$y
$a=$x
$b=$y
gameboard $a,$b,$x,$y
$a=0
$b=$y
gameboard $a,$b,$x,$y
penwidth 5
go $x, 0
forward 2*$x
go 0, $y
turnleft 90
forward 2*$y
```

Here is the finished product:

[image: Screen shot of KTurtle IDE with the Tic-Tac-Toe board]

Comment: Not worth an answer yet but : `$TwoThirdsX` does not seem to be used, your code could probably be easier to understand with more comments and more meaningful variables names. Also, using temporary variable `a` and `b` instead of their value (`0`, `x`, `y`) to call the function `gameboard` is (AFAIK) not useful and makes more convoluted.

Comment: you are right, `$TwoThirdsX` isn't being used. I sort of wrote this on the fly because everything seemed super simple and my first thought was that I wanted a line at 1/3 and 2/3 the width so I created that second variable, but when I implemented the code I went with 1/3 and then 1/3 from current location.  thanks for pointing that out, @Josay.  as for the `a` and `b` variables, I think that what I wanted to do was turn that part into a loop somehow, but you are right, the way it is written now would be better using the actual values.

Comment: This is a good question, and I wish I could help and I'm sure others do as well, but I'm unfamiliar with kTurtle and I bet few people are. The community here is limited mostly to the mainstream languages (C#, Java, some Python, etc).

Comment: I bet there are a couple of people that know more about KTurtle(Logo) than they are letting on... it's been at least 20 years since I worked in Logo myself.  Thank you for looking @LincolnBergeson

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bncVBlTJXD0 Maybe this video will help you.

Comment: I like that. @swapedoc I will have to borrow that code to show my daughter....lol

Comment: I just checked kturtle tutorial after seeing your question and I was surprised to see guys making so creative figures
basically coding something like this depends on your imagination and ofcourse first hand on recursion.Check this out:
http://userbase.kde.org/File:Kturtle_drawing.png

Comment: there is something cool about KTurtle and Logo, the Turtle stays where he stops, so if you run the code again, it runs from his current location.  My daughter she changes the numbers and runs the program over and over again, I think it may be time to introduce her to loops. @swapedoc. she knows a couple of commands,  she is always making cool pictures.

Comment: This is a good resource in case you want to learn and teach
http://docs.kde.org/development/en/kdeedu/kturtle/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15089/discussion-between-malachi-and-swapedoc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've just installed KTurtle for Windows, and ran your code. I never thought a turtle could be so frantic! KTurtle is ..*entertaining* to see in action! I've played with LogoWriter back in high school, an eternity ago; this is very similar (although I was somehow expecting a 16-color, 320x240 resolution.. the shock it was!).

> **Save often.**
>
> KTurtle works on Windows, but it sometimes crashes when you click to run your script. Save often; save every time you want to run it, and it's *workable*. Also whatever you do, don't undock the code pane, it seems impossible to dock it back into the IDE afterwards (and restarting the IDE won't help). If you have access to KTurtle on Ubuntu, by all means don't bother with Windows (assuming it's more stable on Ubuntu).

So I ran it again, at a slower speed.. first thing I'm noticing is that you're missing a `clear` at the beginning of the script (/program?), so that successive executions start off an empty canvas.

Your algorithm is drawing the 4 boards clockwise, starting top-left. Each board is made of 2 horizontal and 2 vertical lines, which means if you skip drawing the larger/bolder lines in the center, the canvas looks like this:

[image: OP's canvas, without the bold lines]

Your algorithm takes good care of not drawing the same line twice and gets the job done, but there's no separation of concerns whatsoever - as was mentioned in @Sjlver's answer, you need *abstractions*; teaching a kid how to *get things done* is nice, teaching the kid how to *think in terms of abstractions* is even nicer. I would go by @Sjlver's recommendation and create a command responsible for drawing a single square (`learn square`), and use a `repeat` loop to keep the code DRY:

```
learn square $x, $y, $size {
    go $x, $y
    repeat 4 {
        edge $size, 90
    }
}

learn edge $size $angle {
    forward $size
    turnright $angle
}
```

Notice the `square` command is only responsible for drawing 4 edges at the specified coordinates - the `edge` command is responsible for drawing a single line and turning the turtle in the specified direction. **It is not responsible for knowing whether or not the pen is up or down**.

I like that you're using `penup` and `pendown` instead of the shorthand `pu` and `pd` - you've used the easier-to-read ones and that's good.

So, now you have a command that can draw a square; now you need one that draws 9 of them to draw a board:

```
learn board $x, $y {
    for $w = 0 to 2 {
        for $h = 0 to 2 {
            square $x + $w * $boxSize, $y + $h * $boxSize, $boxSize
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can have code like this:

```
$boardSize = 150
$boxSize = $boardSize/3

# number of boards to draw in each direction:
$boards = 2

clear
pendown
penwidth 1

for $x = 0 to $boards-1 {
    for $y = 0 to $boards-1 {
        board $x * $boardSize, $y * $boardSize
    }
}
```

It's slower than your code, and it's not as efficient (pretty much every line get drawn more than once), but *thinking in abstractions*, in terms of *functions that do only one thing*, is more important than getting a script to do what you need it to do.

This is the result:

[image: a uniform 6x6 grid of squares]

Now you want have a black border around each board, right? The code to do that is pretty much already written!

```
penwidth 5
for $x = 0 to $boards - 1 {
    for $y = 0 to $boards - 1 {
        square $x * $boardSize, $y * $boardSize, $boardSize
    }
}
```

Now this leaves the "script" part doing 3 things: declaring global-scope variables, drawing the boards, and drawing the outlines. Here's the final script, with the result:

```
learn square $x, $y, $size {
    go $x, $y
    repeat 4 {
        edge $size, 90
    }
}

learn edge $size, $angle {
    turnright $angle
    forward $size
}

learn board $x, $y {
    for $w = 0 to 2 {
        for $h = 0 to 2 {
            square $x+$w*$boxSize, $y+$h*$boxSize, $boxSize
        }
    }
}

learn drawBoards {
    for $x = 0 to $boards-1 {
        for $y = 0 to $boards-1 {
            board $x*$boardSize, $y*$boardSize
        }
    }
}

learn drawOutlines {
    for $x = 0 to $boards-1 {
        for $y = 0 to $boards-1 {
            square $x*$boardSize, $y*$boardSize, $boardSize
        }
    }
}

$boardSize = 150
$boxSize = $boardSize/3
$boards = 2

clear
pendown

penwidth 1
drawBoards

penwidth 5
drawOutlines
```

The "script" part is now only in charge of controlling the high-level stuff; the lower-level actual looping and drawing is abstracted away into commands with meaningful names, that start with a verb, and as a bonus, the turtle ends up right in the middle!

[image: finished board, 6x6 1px grid with 2x2 5px outlines, turtle in the center]

Comment: Note: `$boardSize = 200` would fill up the entire canvas (400x400). ..oh, just noticed it was configurable.. oh well!

Comment: LOL, thank you for the Detailed answer. I am going to install KTurtle on my Windows 8.1 machine and use some of this to create the playable game.  might take me a little while but I think it will be plenty fun

Comment: I purposely used the long hand versions of all the commands because it is easier to read, and my daughter is just learning how to read so I think she should not be taking shortcuts.

Comment: it is more stable on Ubuntu, probably more so on Edubuntu.  KDE was made for Linux not for Windows, that is the problem I think I am thinking about finally trying to look into opensource projects and I think KDE and/or KTurtle (on Windows) will be the first one.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not a kTurtle programmer, but there are some general things that could be improved:

- Use good, descriptive names for your variables. You might use `CanvasWidth` instead of `CanvasX`, and `left`, `bottom`, `right`, `top` instead of `a`, `b`, `x`, `y`.
- Try to make your code easy to understand. If I look at your gameboard function, I find it hard to figure out what it does. You could split it in smaller units. For example, you could have a `rectangle` function, that you then call nine times. It also helps if you write a comment describing each unit.
- Whenever you do something repeatedly (like drawing nine squares, or four gameboards), you can use a loop.

Comment: there actually isn't 9 squares, there is 4 lines for each board.  but I like the way you are thinking, it maybe be easier to draw a board with 9 squares than to try and draw the lines to create a board.